# PHP Regex for Filtering Domain Names in _POST Username

Tags: php, regex, post

I have some hardcoded if/else statements to set $page variable - (for later use in header: ".page") - to a given website based on the $_POST["username"] input.

CODE:

```
if ($_POST["username"] == "username1@domain1.com") {
$page = "http://www.google.com";
}
 else if ($_POST["username"] == "username2@domain1.com"){
$page = "http://www.yahoo.com";
}
 else if ($_POST["username"] == "username1@domain2.com"){
$page = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
}
 else if ($_POST["username"] == "username2@domain2.com"){
$page = "http://www.serverfault.com";
}
 else if ($_POST["username"] == "username@domain3.com"){
$page = "http://www.superuser.com";
}
 else if (!preg_match($domain2.com, $_POST["username"]))  { //THIS IS VERY WRONG
$page = "http://www.backblaze.com";
}
else{
$page = "DefaultBackupPage.php";
}
```

I am trying to say if your username has "@domain.com" at the end of it, set the $page to, in this case backblaze.com, but could be anything.

I am aware it is messy, I don't actually like this implementation. It just has to fit in this schema and I need a quick fix!

The current error I am receiving is that the regular expression is empty. I am hoping this is a no brainer for someone who knows PHP - which I have been hastily trying to learn!

Comment: The variable `$domain2.com` is none. It's a concatenation of `$domain2` and a bare constant `com`. Did you set the former at all? If you don't know nothing about regex, use `stristr($_POST["username"], "@domain2.com")` instead. Also use an array map instead of a lengthy `if` chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/@domain2\.com$/i',$_POST['username']))
```

will catch username ending with `domain2.com`. Please note the escaping backward slash for the dot. If you want to test against the opposite (aka. does **NOT** end with `domain2.com`) then use an exclamation mark before the [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function.

Is this what you were asking?

**EDIT 1:** I added the `i` flag to the pattern to make it look for a case-insensitive match.

**EDIT 2:** For the sake of readability and control I would wrap this in a function instead, but that's my own preference so it's not the suggested approach or anything. In case your code is long and complicated…

```
function get_page($username) {
    $username = strtolower($username);
    switch ($username) {
        case "username1@domain1.com"    : return "http://www.google.com";
        case "username2@domain1.com"    : return "http://www.yahoo.com";
        case "username1@domain2.com"    : return "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
        case "username2@domain2.com"    : return "http://www.serverfault.com";
        case "username@domain3.com"     : return "http://www.superuser.com";
    }
    return preg_match('/@domain2\.com$/',$username) ?
    "http://www.backblaze.com" : "DefaultBackupPage.php";
}

$page = get_page($_POST['username']);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was asking. Thanks mate! I am still learning and the syntax was doing my head in. Thank you for a very quick turnaround!' - edit: Will accept this answer ASAP. Can't because you fixed this too quick and I am new on this site.

Comment: Double escape the . with two slashes. Just to stay awesome.

Comment: @James Glad to help. Welcome to SO :)

Comment: @inhan (or others). I have a follow up question. I've now been told that we might have hundreds of usernames. So far, I can handle the redirect, but for authentication, can i do regex like [a-z][A-Z]@domain.com for a username value in an array like

$usernames = array("username1@domain1.com", "username2@domain1.com",);

Comment: @James Best practice for authentication is to create a class that connects to a database and checks values there. If all you need is to check the email(s) you will need a much more complicated pattern. Regardless, you should create a new question here in SO with detailed information about this.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
 else if(!preg_match($domain2.com, $_POST["username"]))
```

has to be:

```
 else if(!preg_match("/domain2\.com/", $_POST["username"]))
```